# CollectionFS get url from Client

Tags: javascript, meteor, gridfs, spacebars, collectionfs

I am developing my first meteor app, and have just implemented uploading images using CollectionFS and gridfs. I can successfully view my uploaded images using `<img src="{{this.url}}">` but I need to access it from the client in Meteor. I am trying to use a field from another document in a collection and call an image based on if the fields match in the metadata. (Basically joining the two documents using a Spacebars registerHelper).  I am hesitant to embed the other documents with the image, because I am worried about the space requirements.

I have tried looking through the Meteor-cfs-ui package but am having trouble translating it into my own Spacebar registerHelper. Looking through the UI Helpers page on Meteor-CollectionFS, has a broken link to where my answer I believe resides.

I can view all images I upload so that is not the problem using {{this.url}}. Just trying to get the url for the images in the collection using a query on the FS.Collection on the client side is troubling me.

Here is my code:

**client.html**

```
    {{#each individualBuyOffers}}
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">

            <h4>{{shoePict make}}</h4>

        </div>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
```

**client.js**

```
      UI.registerHelper('shoePict',function(context,options){

         if(context){
             //The goal is to query the Pictures collection
             //and find the url to the picture I want
             //then output it to HTML from the SafeString
             //Pictures is my FS.Collection
             var url = Pictures.find({'metadata.make': context});
             //var collection = FS._collections[Pictures];
             //return collection ? collection.findOne(id) : null;
             //I know this is not the right statement
             return new Spacebars.SafeString( "<img src=\"{{this.url}}\">") ;
             }
      });
```

If there are any other easier solutions to attaching a picture from CollectionFS to another document through html, I would love to hear it. I am just trying to learn. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From js you can access the url of collectionFS file with `fileObj.url()` for example:

```
var url = Pictures.findOne({'metadata.make': context}).url();
```

Comment: Wow, that was much simpler that expected, Thank you.